# box-shadow causing h-scrollbar to show in Opera

Tags: opera, css

```
#wrap{
 box-shadow: inset 0 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0, 0.75); 
}
```

The element has 100% width.

Why do I get the scroll bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
box-shadow: 10px 30px rgb(0,0,0, 0.75);
```

Comment: True, For support in Opera and IE9 and higher you need to include the official W3C variant of the property, without prefixes: box-shadow

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding overflow:hidden to the parent element, tx